# How to delete the Azure Active directory users from Azure Portal ( the Users were created from the server 2016 visual studio community VM )

Tags: entra-id

I have created users lets say U1, U2 ,U3, U4 and U5 from the Virtual machine's Active directory (windows server 2016 with visual studio 2017 community edition). and while cleaning up the resources I deleted the virtual machine by mistake before deleting the users that were created using the VM. 
Any help on this matter is appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Shravya.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you rephrase?

Comment: I  have a few uses in my Azure Active Directory and I am unable to delete them . I do not have the access to delete these users . When I checked further I found out that these users were created in the Virtual machine  and now that virtual machine is deleted and the users are left out and I am unable to delete them .

Answer (score 0):

If these users were created in Azure AD then they can be deleted from Azure AD. If they were created as local user accounts on the VM then they were deleted when the VM was deleted.

Comment: Yes but unfortunately they were not deleted and all these users still show up on the Azure active directory.

Comment: OK, then delete them.

Comment: That is what I am unable to do as  I do not have rights for deleting these accounts from the Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Well then you need someone who does have those rights to delete them.